# Power series in $\mathbb{Q}_5$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, power-series, p-adic-number-theory

Could you help me to find the first five positions of the power series in $\mathbb{Q}_5$ of $\frac{1}{2}$?

How can I do this? Is there a general formula?

Comment: what do you mean by power series of $\frac{1}{2}$?? You mean $5$ adic expansion?

Comment: I assume so, the exercise asks what I have written above.
$$$$
So, how can I find the $5$ adic expansion?

Comment: Do you know what is $|\frac{1}{2}|_5$??

Comment: $$ \left | \frac{1}{2}\right |_5=1$$

How can we use this?

Comment: That helps me to choose what power of $5$ to start with...

Comment: Could you explain it further to me how we can use this? I haven't understood it...

Comment: Ok... Let me start from scratch... Do you know how does a p adic expansion look like..

Comment: It is of the form $x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n p^n, a_n \in \{0,1, \dots, p-1 \}$, right?

Comment: Yes... That is what i have written in my answer... Please spend some time on observing the hints..

Comment: Ok!! But where do we use the fact that $\left | \frac{1}{2}\right |_5=1$

Comment: Oh.. You are getting confused with that?? May be we can neglect that for a while.. Once we understand the rest we can come back to that later.. I have edited my answer.. please see if that can help you

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Ah... Yes... I was not sure where i was missing.... Now i got it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it doesn't quite make sense to say 'expand this in power series' as infinite power series usually diverge in the Euclidean metric. You thus need to work with the $p$-adic metric over $\Bbb Z$ which can be complicated to 'visualize' sometimes. I actually prefer the algebraic way to do it :

$\mathbf{Z}_5$, by the inverse limit definition, is $\{(x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots) \in \prod \mathbf{Z}/5^k \mathbf{Z} : x_k = x_{k-1} \pmod {5^k}\}$. To get the element in $\mathbf{Z}_5$ corresponding to $1/2$, consider the infinite tuple $$(1/2 \bmod{5}, 1/2 \bmod{5^2}, 1/2 \bmod{5^3}, \cdots) = (3, 13, 63, \cdots) \in \prod \mathbf{Z}/5^k \mathbf{Z}$$ The corresponding series $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_k 5^k$ (converging in the $5$-adic sense) is defined as the series such that $n$-th partial sum of this series evaluates to $x_n$ :

$$3 = \sum_{k = 0}^0 a_k 5^k \Longrightarrow a_0 = 3 \\ 13 = \sum_{k = 0}^1 a_k 5^k = 13 \Longrightarrow a_1 = (13-a_0)/5 = 2 \\ 63 = \sum_{k = 0}^2 a_k5^k \Longrightarrow a_2 = (63 - a_0 - a_1  \cdot 5)/25 = 2
 \\ \vdots$$

Show rigorously that $a_0 = 3$ and $a_n = 2$ if $n > 0$. Thus conclude that the first five terms of the $5$-adic series rep of $1/2$ is $3 + 2 \cdot 5 + 2 \cdot 5^2 + 2 \cdot 5^3 + 2 \cdot 5^4 + \cdots$

Comment: I have also an other question? Could I also formulate it like that?
$$$$
We solve the equation $2x \equiv 3 \pmod 5$
$$2x \equiv 1 \pmod 5 \Rightarrow x \equiv 3 \pmod 5 \Rightarrow \exists a_1 \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ such that } x=3+5a_1$$

$$2x \equiv 1 \pmod {5^2} \Rightarrow 2(3+5a_1) \equiv 1 \pmod {5^2} \Rightarrow 5+10a_1 \equiv 0 \pmod {5^2} \Rightarrow 1+2a_1 \equiv 0 \pmod 5 \Rightarrow 2a_1 \equiv -1 \pmod 5 \Rightarrow 2a_1 \equiv 4 \pmod 5 \Rightarrow a_1 \equiv 2 \pmod 5 \Rightarrow a_1=2+5a_2$$

So: $x=3+5(2+5a_2)$ and so on?

Comment: @evinda Indeed, you can. I'd say now you've figured out how Hensel's lemma comes to play =). Well done.

Comment: Balarka Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Which is the easiest way to find for example a $x$, such that $2x \equiv 1 \pmod {5^3}$ ?

Comment: @evinda If in general $2x = 1 \pmod{5^n}$ then $x = (5^n + 1)/2$.

Comment: Could you explain me further how we conclude that $x=\frac{5^n+1}{2}$?

Comment: For $n=4$ we have $$x=\frac{5^4+1}{2}=313$$ But... $$2 \cdot 313 \neq 1 \pmod {5^4}$$ Or am I wrong?

Comment: You're wrong.${}$

Comment: Where am I wrong?

Comment: $2 \cdot 313 = 626 = 625 + 1$. So $2 \cdot 313$ modulo $5^4$ is...?

Comment: A ok.. How can we show that $a_n=2, \forall n>0$?

Comment: Use that $x = (5^n + 1)/2$, as mentioned above.

Comment: A ok.. if we want to find $8x \equiv 3 \pmod {5^n}$, can we use again the formula: $\displaystyle{x=\frac{5^n+3}{8}}$ ?

Comment: Sure why not @evinda. That's pretty elementary stuff. You need to revise elementary number theory a bit before jumping onto p-adics and whatnots first.

Answer (score 3):

See that $$\frac{-1}{2}=\frac{2}{1-5}=2(1+5+5^2+\cdots)$$

Now, $$\frac{1}{2}=1-\frac{1}{2}=1+2(1+5+5^2+\cdots)$$

Now this makes sense..

Thanks to Mr.Jyrki Lahtonen..

Comment: but ... $-2 \neq 3$

Comment: @mercio I was thinking as $-2\equiv 3\mod 5$ i can replace $-2$ with $3$...

Comment: yes but $\Bbb Q_5$ is not $\Bbb Z/5 \Bbb Z$ so I don't know why you would do that ?

Comment: But the Maple command $padic:-evalp(1/2, 5) $ produces $$ 3+2*5+2*5^2+2*5^3
+2*5^{4}+2*5^{5}+2*5^{6}+2*5^{7}+2*5^{8}+O(5^9)
.$$

Comment: OH... I think my short cut is not working here.. I would soon come with an answer explaining usual procedure..

Comment: @user64494 : Yes.. I was wrong... was a bit  over reactive  and ended up doing nonsense..

Comment: @mercio : YEs.. I was wrong.. Please have a look at another answer of mine...

Answer (score 3):

By $5$ adic expansion we mean an expansion of following form with $a_i\in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ $$\frac{1}{2}=a_0+a_1\cdot5+a_2\cdot5^2+\cdots$$

$$\frac{1}{2}-a_0=5\cdot(a_1+a_2\cdot5+\cdots)$$
We want $a_0$ to be choosen such that $5$ divides $2a_0-1$ (Why??)

We need $a_1$ to be suhc that $5^2$ divides $\frac{1}{2}-a_0-a_1\cdot5$ (Why??)

Do you see now how to choose $a_2$??

Comment: I found that the expansion is $\frac{1}{2}=3+2 \cdot 5+ 2 \cdot 5^2+ 2 \cdot 5^3+ 2 \cdot 5^4+ \dots$. Is it right?

Comment: Do you believe that?? :) :) Hope it is correct....

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't this way to find the expansion right? :/

Comment: Yes it is!!!!!!

Comment: @evinda : Do you have any more questions??

Comment: Could you explain me how I can show that $\frac{1}{2}$ is a $5-$adic integer?

Comment: Your question is not so clear... do you mind to make it a bit more clear?

Comment: I am asked to show that the number $\frac{1}{2}$ is an integer 5-adic number. But, how can I do this?

Comment: Can't we show that a 5-adic is an integer? :/

Comment: I want to show that $\frac{1}{2}$ is a 5-adic INTEGER.. Can we not show that a p-adic number is an integer?

Comment: Oh... I guess he wants to see if "coefficients" of expansion of $\frac{1}{2}$ are integers... So, If that is the case then you have "showed" that it is in fact an integer...

Comment: But.. I have to show that $\frac{1}{2}$ is a 5-adic integer, before I find the first five positions of its power series. Is the fact that $\frac{1}{2}$ is a 5-adic integer maybe a condition, that has to stand in order to find a power series of a number in $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Comment: Oh... Yes.. Now i got your question.. See that we have seen that $|\frac{1}{2}|_5=1$... These are what we consider as integers.. p adic numbers for which "norm" is less than or equal to $1$..

Comment: So, if we would have for example $x=\frac{1}{5^2}$, it would be $|x|_5=2$. Would that mean that $\frac{1}{5^2}$ is not a 5-adic integer?

Comment: Yes....!!!!!!!!

Comment: Is there a theorem that states it?

Comment: That is definition...

Comment: I have also an other question? Could I also formulate it like that?
$$$$
We solve the equation $2x \equiv 3 \pmod 5$
$$2x \equiv 1 \pmod 5 \Rightarrow x \equiv 3 \pmod 5 \Rightarrow \exists a_1 \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ such that } x=3+5a_1$$

$$2x \equiv 1 \pmod {5^2} \Rightarrow 2(3+5a_1) \equiv 1 \pmod {5^2} \Rightarrow 5+10a_1 \equiv 0 \pmod {5^2} \Rightarrow 1+2a_1 \equiv 0 \pmod 5 \Rightarrow 2a_1 \equiv -1 \pmod 5 \Rightarrow 2a_1 \equiv 4 \pmod 5 \Rightarrow a_1 \equiv 2 \pmod 5 \Rightarrow a_1=2+5a_2$$

So: $x=3+5(2+5a_2)$ and so on?

Comment: @evinda : Yes.... That also works...

Answer (score 3):

This kind of expansion is very easy to do by hand, using elementary-school methods, but writing your infinite $5$-ary expansions running to the left rather than to the right.
For instance, when you subtract $1$ from $0$, you get $\dots4444.\,$, where the term for $4$ is at the right end, the term for $4\cdot5$ is to the left of that, and the term for $4\cdot5^2$ is just to the left of that, and so on. So the $5$-ary expansion of $-1$ is a plain geometric series evaluated as $a/(1-r)$ with $a=4$ and $r=5$, surenough evaluating to $-1$.

Now for the only slightly more difficult expansion of $1/2$:
[image: dividing 2 into 1]

Since the expansion is going to run infinitely to the left, you put the divisor $2$ on the right and the dividend $1$ to the left of that. You think of what integer between $0$ and $4$ gives a product with $2$ that has $1$ as its rightmost $5$-ary digit. That’s $3$, of course, since six has the $5$-ary expansion $11.\,$, and you now do that multiplication, putting the $11$ under your dividend $1$. Now subtract, as you do in long division. Ah, but this is our known expansion of $-1$, all fours. From here on it’s easy to divide by $2$, there are no carries or borrows,and you see immediately that the expansion of $1/2$ is $\dots22223.\,$, that is, $3+2\cdot5+2\cdot5^2+2\cdot5^3+\cdots$. Let’s check that. We have the initial term $3$, and then the pure geometric series with $a=10$ (in decimal notation, now) and $r=5$, in other words, your expansion gives $3 -10/4$, surenough just right.

Comment: LOL! Now why did I not think about explaining it this way? Skipping the part of grade school division, and jumping directly to a method useful for proving that the expansion is eventually periodic? I guess it shows that I have even less experience teaching $p$-adics than I have using them :-)